# VSTS Nuget Publisher Task Issues

Tags: package, nuget, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

When i use the nuget publisher task as part of a build definition it seems to error no matter what I do, with the error:

```
##[error]Unhandled: %s is not a solution file. Check the 'path to solution or packages.config' property of the NuGetInstaller task.
```

I have no idea what this means of what I can do to resolve it. The full log for the task is:

```
2016-07-28T13:39:44.3146094Z Set workingFolder to default: C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\1.103.0\tasks\NuGetPublisher\0.2.0
2016-07-28T13:39:44.8813939Z ##[debug]agent.workFolder=C:\a
2016-07-28T13:39:44.8813939Z ##[debug]loading inputs and endpoints
2016-07-28T13:39:44.8823941Z ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_$/
2016-07-28T13:39:44.8843932Z ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_PARAMETER_$/_ACCESSTOKEN
2016-07-28T13:39:44.8853942Z ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_PARAMETER_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION_ACCESSTOKEN
2016-07-28T13:39:44.8863939Z ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SCHEME_$/
2016-07-28T13:39:44.8863939Z ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SCHEME_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION
2016-07-28T13:39:44.8873940Z ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION
2016-07-28T13:39:44.8873940Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_FEEDNAME
2016-07-28T13:39:44.8883941Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_NUGETFEEDTYPE
2016-07-28T13:39:44.8883941Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_PRECREDPROVIDERNUGET
2016-07-28T13:39:44.8883941Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_SEARCHPATTERN
2016-07-28T13:39:44.8893942Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_VERBOSITY
2016-07-28T13:39:44.8903938Z ##[debug]loaded 11
2016-07-28T13:39:45.0733941Z ##[debug]check path : C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\1.103.0\tasks\NuGetPublisher\0.2.0\task.json
2016-07-28T13:39:45.0743936Z ##[debug]set resource file to: C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\1.103.0\tasks\NuGetPublisher\0.2.0\task.json
2016-07-28T13:39:45.0753931Z ##[debug]system.culture=en-US
2016-07-28T13:39:45.0784231Z ##[debug]searchPattern=C:\a\1\s\**\*.nupkg;
2016-07-28T13:39:45.0784231Z ##[debug]System.DefaultWorkingDirectory=C:\a\1\s
2016-07-28T13:39:45.0793937Z ##[debug]Matching glob pattern: C:\a\1\s\**\*.nupkg
2016-07-28T13:39:45.0793937Z ##[debug]Index of first wildcard: 9
2016-07-28T13:39:45.0803939Z ##[debug]find root dir: C:\a\1
2016-07-28T13:39:45.3943927Z ##[debug]find C:\a\1
2016-07-28T13:39:45.3953940Z ##[debug]3101 matches.
2016-07-28T13:39:45.5293937Z ##[debug]check path : C:\a\1\s
2016-07-28T13:39:45.5353925Z ##[debug]task result: Failed
2016-07-28T13:39:45.5503936Z ##[error]Unhandled: %s is not a solution file. Check the 'path to solution or packages.config' property of the NuGetInstaller task.
```

I have even tried disabling all other steps and only having the publisher step as active, with a filter that won't pick up any files and yet it still fails at the same point.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the contents of the "Path to solution or packages.config" line item in the NuGet Publisher task configuration?

Comment: For reference, I've started getting this too Nothing has changed at my end, and builds have started to fail. This is after MS say "problem fixed".... in case it's their fault ;p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue: [NuGet Publish Error on Version 0.2.0](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/2150).

Please try the workaround below:

> As a workaround, check the 'Path/Pattern to nupkg' for doubled
>   semicolons, or semicolons at the beginning or end of the value. We had
>   an internal report of that as well, and a trailing semicolon
>   (resulting in an "empty" pattern)is what triggered that bug for them.

Comment: This was my problem. Before the update, my path had a semi colon at the end and worked fine. after the update it threw the error but on removing the semi colon, it has started working again. argh, such simple things! thanks for your help

Comment: I can also confirm this fixes the issue. Thanks for posting it, Is there a fix in the works before I have to go and change every build script for my large micro-service suite ?